# How can I interpolate lat/long over time in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, geometry, interpolation

I've got two tables, simplified as seen below.

```
CREATE TABLE value(
    Timestamp DATETIME2,
    Value float NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Timestamp)
);

CREATE TABLE location(
    Timestamp DATETIME2,
    Position GEOMETRY NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(Timestamp)
);
```

Performing a simple LEFT JOIN such as:

```
SELECT V.Timestamp, V.Value, L.Position 
FROM   value V
       LEFT JOIN location L ON V.Timestamp = L.Timestamp;
```

This yields all the values but there are NULL's present where there isn't an exact match on `Timestamp`.

My goal is to get an interpolated position for every value in the value table.  I need to somehow interpolate values in my query and this is where I'm getting stuck.

EDIT: I've since discovered I can add a CASE statement to check for NULL

```
SELECT 
    V.Timestamp, 
    V.Value, 
    CASE WHEN L.Position IS NULL THEN 
        (<something clever here>) 
    ELSE 
        L.Position 
    END As Position

FROM value V
     LEFT JOIN location L ON V.Timestamp = L.Timestamp;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at the Spatial Tools library?  [link](http://sqlspatialtools.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Current%20Contents&referringTitle=Home)
They have a interpolation function that looks to be what you need:

> SqlGeometry InterpolateBetweenGeom(SqlGeometry start, SqlGeometry end,
>   double distance)

I amended my first example to now calculate the midpoint of the two closest points, but I think the above library is a much better option.  To use my function, you pass in the timestamps for those NULL postions and function returns the midpoint as a geom position.

This might be of use for someone in a similar situation:

```
   if object_id('dbo.fn_CalcMidPointByTime') is not null
        drop function dbo.fn_CalcMidPointByTime;
    go  
    create function [dbo].[fn_CalcMidPointByTime] (@baseTimestamp datetime2)
    returns geometry
    as
    begin
        declare @return geometry,
                @fromPoint geometry,
                @toPoint geometry;

        declare @stage table (i tinyint, position geometry);

        -- stage the high / low points
        insert into @stage (i, position)
            select  row_number() over(order by d.[Timestamp] asc), position.ToString()
            from    (   select top(2) [Timestamp]
                        from    dbo.Location
                        order by abs(datediff(ms, [Timestamp], @baseTimestamp)) asc
                    ) as d([Timestamp])
            join    dbo.Location l on
                    d.[Timestamp] = l.[Timestamp];

        select @fromPoint = position from @stage where i = 1;
        select @toPoint = position from @stage where i = 2;

        -- create linestring from the two points
        declare @ls geometry = geometry::Parse(@fromPoint.STUnion(@toPoint).ToString()).STConvexHull().ToString();

        -- draw a rectangle around the two points, and choose the center
        select @return = @ls.STEnvelope().STCentroid();
        return @return;
    end
    go
```

Comment: Thanks for the input - that's a nice approach but I really need to get a linear interpolation between the two closest points in time and not just the closest.

Comment: Thanks for the link - it does look exactly like what I'm looking for!  I will take a look and update.

Comment: The library does the interpolation perfectly.  Thanks for the link.  I also upvoted @Randy answer because I need to create a temp table before doing the interpolation so it's a combination of both answers.  Thanks a lot guys!

Comment: Are you calculating the distance as a ratio of the time diff between the two points?  I would think it would need to be weighted base on time.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should change your query to return 3 sets of values on every row:

these should be the largest time and position that is less than the current one,

the current time and position,

and the smallest time and position greater then the current one.

in this way, each row will have enough info to do the math...

Comment: Hmm... that's not a bad idea.  I will try that and get back to you.  Thanks for the tip.

Comment: I've gotten this to somewhat work with a temp table and then querying that temp table.  The only hitch is that I had to use INT instead of geometry for my position to be able to do the interpolation math.  Do you have any experience working with Geometry Points?

Comment: not in the spatial database definition no.. i have always rolled my own.  i'm surprised that you couldnt use float.